# Fetch request not fetching backend object - nextjs and express

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I have a Nextjs frontend trying to make a fetch request to my node and express backend but it's not happening for some reason. I'm trying to access this object in the backend: `{"data": ["data1", "data2", "data3"]}` but I'm not able to even fetch it. Here is my backend code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({"data": ["data1", "data2", "data3"]})
})

app.listen(5000, () => { console.log("Server started on port 5000") })
```

Here is my next.js file trying to make this request:

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';


const Product = () => {

  const [backendData, setBackendData] = useState([{}])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api").then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(
      data => {
        setBackendData(data)
      }
    )
  }, [])

  return (
      <div>

          {(typeof backendData.data === 'undefined') ? (
            <p>Loading...</p>
          ) : (
            backendData.data.map((data, i) => (
              <p key={i}>{data}</p>
            ))
          )}
      </div>

  );
}

export default Product
```

I've included this line in my `package.json` file `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",` so it should be going to that link and when I search `http://localhost:5000` in my browser, I get the object that I've written in the backend like this: `{"data":["data1","data2","data3"]}`.

When I click on `Network` when I hit inspect on the page, the fetch request doesn't show up either.

Does anyone know why I'm unable to fetch this object in nextjs?

Comment: Have you tried setting the fetch url to http://localhost:5000/api?

Comment: yes, but that still hasn't worked. Is there something different I have to do when dealing with `Next.js` apps and using express?

Comment: What would be the trigger for the fetch request?

Comment: There's not a trigger that a user would have to worry about, the useEffect would just run upon the component being built

Comment: Do you not see a request to `http://localhost:3000/api` (your local Next.js server) being made on page load?

Comment: No I don't see a request